# Is it possible to import multi-set parameters via pyodbc in a Pyomo Abstract Model?

Tags: python, pyodbc, pyomo

Has anyone been successful in loading a multiset parameter in Pyomo using pyodbc?

Example:

```
    load "Driver={PostgreSQL};Database=db;Server=srv;User=user;" using='pyodbc' query="SELECT A, B, C FROM tbl": [A, B] C;
```

The corresponding entry in the model is

```
    model.C = Param(model.A,model.B)
```

Loading one-dimensional sets and parameters does work.  The query above results in a `'AbstractModel' object has no attribute 'C' error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by converting the abstract model to a concrete model and importing the data via psycopg2 connections.